# How to add changing event to List<T> class in C#?

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, user-controls

I want to add an event to the List generic class in C# in order to handle changing items of list in case that a new item is added or removed. I create class and inherit it from List class. Since the Add, Insert, and Remove methods of this class can't be overrode, I define new Add, Insert, and Remove methods by new keyword and call the parent methods and then raise my event. I used this class as a property in an User Control. In design mode when I change the collection with provided GUI in .net development studio, the event does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Here is an example of defining such a class

```
public class SelectorItemCollection : List<SelectorItem>
{
    public new void Add(SelectorItem Item)
    {

        //Call parent method
        base.Add(Item);

        //Raise changing event
        this.OnCollectionChanged();

    }
}
```

I defined a property in my user control class like this:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public SelectorItemCollection Items { get; }
```

My desired state that when I change the items in this dialog, I want to raise a changing event from collection class.

[image]

Comment: Subclassing `List<T>` is dangerous, because the methods (`Add` etc) are **not** `virtual`. You could derive from `Collection<T>` (where they **are** `virtual`), but the answers are right in that it is easier to use (or derive from) `BindingList<T>` here, since that has everything you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a collection class that already supports such notifications, like [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) or [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) (if you're using data binding in WPF, use the former; in Windows Forms, use the latter).

If you want to implement your own, don't inherit from `List<T>`, because it was not designed for inheritance. Instead, you could use [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) as your base class.

Answer (score 2):

Have at look at `BindingList<T>` instead, which seems to be what you are trying to replicate

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `System.ComponentModel.BindingList<SelectorItem>` which has various events on it.